# Windows 10 Light

Tags: windows, windows-phone, windows-10, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I am trying to turn on a windows 10 device's camera light. As of right now I am only able to get the light to briefly flash then turns back off. Is there a way to make the light stay on. I am currently using:

```
using (var lamp = await Lamp.GetDefaultAsync())
{
   lamp.BrightnessLevel = 1.0F;
   lamp.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put the lamp in a `using` statement which disposes it when execution exits the block. Disposing the lamp turns it off.